# MapBox GL JS - Markers or Layers

Tags: geojson, cartography, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Ok. I've a server which send me a geojson data, according to the specifications. I'm using mapbox gl js, and not sure what type of method to choose: 1) creating a layer with geojson properties of geometry + adding an image to it and creating label; 2) creating a marker for each of this geojson feature.

Which method influence performance and which variant is the best, taking into account that the geojson has 1000 features inside?